# Polymorphism In javascript with prototype

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

What does the second line of this code means?

```
var Square = function (){
Square.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype); // Meaning?
Square.prototype.draw = function (){
     return "I am a square";
}
```

Comment: have you looked up in the documentation about this? What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: The second line is like `extends` but without `class` keyword.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on prototypes. Remember JS doesn't have classes, it has prototypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's creating an object that uses the object `Shape.prototype` refers to as its prototype. This is so that instances created via `new Square` inherit from that object, which in turn inherits from `Shape.prototype`, and so those instances have the features of both.

It's incomplete, it should be followed by:

```
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;
```

---

Of course, since ES2015 came out and was well-supported by transpilers (nd now by modern browsers and other modern JavaScript environments), there's little reason to hook things up this verbose and error-prone way.